# Multithreading in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm new to `MultiThreading`.

I have an `UITableView` with few rows. When i select one row there will be some action taking place in the server. So that will take some time to finish the action. So when i want to select other row in the table it takes time to perform action, ie after the 1st row finishes the action this row will start the action.

So all i want to do is that, when the 1st row is selected and the action is preforming, and when i select the 2nd row , the  1st row action should open an new thread and run in that thread, and after the action is completed it should kill the thread.

I want this way to happen for the rows in the `UITableview`.

Can Anyone Help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

Read up on Grand Central Dispatch: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

Here is a basic example on setting up a thread:

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Add code here to do background processing
    //
    //
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // Add code here to update the UI/send notifications based on the
        // results of the background processing
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use asynchronous requests with `NSURLConnection`, you can simply start the action when the user selects a row, and when the async request returns, you can do whatever you need to do there. No need for Grand Central Dispatch or worrying too much about threads.

By default, the delegate methods for NSURLConnection will execute in the main run loop, so you don't even have to worry about writing thread safe code. However, you can choose to run them in a separate thread if you'd like.